# Swift indexPathsForSelectedRows returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a tableView, goal is to implement a expandible/collapsible tableView cells. The number of cells is completely dynamic.

I have things working, but with a small problem. I am using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to toggle expand/collapse cell. So what happens now is the toggle executes by tapping anywhere on the cell. :-(

Inside the cell, I have two UIViews (Header and Detail precisely). I need the toggle expand/collapse to work only when I tap on Header and not the whole cell.

For that, I am fetching the indexPath like here but that doesn't work since indexPathsForSelectedRows returns nil.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myVouchers.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            return 150.0
        }
        else {
            return 40.0
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CollapsedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollapsedCell

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(VoucherDetailViewController.expandCell(_:)))
        (cell as! CollapsedCell).headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        return cell
    }

    func getIndexPathForSelectedCell() -> NSIndexPath? {

        var indexPath: NSIndexPath?

        if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count > 0 {   //**nil is returned here**
            indexPath = (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?[0])! as NSIndexPath
        }
        return indexPath
    }

    func expandCell(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let myIndexPath = getIndexPathForSelectedCell() {
            if selectedIndex == myIndexPath.row {
                selectedIndex = -1
            }
            else {
                selectedIndex = myIndexPath.row
            }

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
```

Could someone give me a clue why the indexPathsForSelectedRows returns nil?

Many Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** 
[Current Working demo](http://g.recordit.co/iP3M72InAZ.gif)

When I add my expand cell logic in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and remove my tapGestureRecognizer for the view inside the cell - it looks like this -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            selectedIndex = -1
        }
        else {
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You got this bug because

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

reloads and deselect your rows.

You just select row, after that, you reload row (this action will deselect this row) and later you want to get a selected rows using

```
tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

but table view does not have any selected rows at this moment.

As a solution, you can store selected indexPath in new variable, and use this variable instead of

```
tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

Comment: makes sense! store selected indexPath in a new variable - can you please elaborate?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu, just create variable in your controller and save new value of the indexPath to this variable in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I should either use didSelectRowAtIndexPath or the tapGesture for my view in the cell. If I use both, only the tapGesture works and didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Comment: my question is how do I execute the toggle logic by tapping only on the headerView, and not on the whole cell

Answer (score 1):

From the [indexPathsForSelectedRows documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows):

> The value of this property is nil if there are no selected rows.

Therefore:

```
guard let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else {
   return nil
}

return selectedRows[0]
```

(no check for `count` is needed, the method never returns an empty array).

By the way, you could simplify the condition using:

```
return tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.first
```

or, if your table does not support multiple selection, directly call:

```
return tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

which is already there.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I always get nil for tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow even though I select a row. How do I fix this nil issue?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu, tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow will always return nil if you reloaded table view data before that. Because after reloading data, table view reset all of the cell selection.

Comment: @V.Khambir If you need to keep selection, don't reload the cells. If you need to only update the height of the cell, don't call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. It's enough to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` with nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

> As **Sulthan** said try below code in place of **reload**

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```